# What is the content-type and x-ms-version to be used to load the azure datalake file to azure datalake gen2?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I have to load data lake file(csv format) to azure datalake storage gen2 using logic app.I have created logic app using http action,able to create the file and appended the data.for the next  http action need to give the length.what is content-type to be used for files to load data into datalake storage gen2.i'm getting error like The uploaded data is not contiguous or the position query parameter value is not equal to the length of the file after appending the uploaded data and errocode: InvalidFlushPosition
Can someone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's version '2018-11-09'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I need content-type as well to load file

Comment: You should just use Content-Type: text/plain for that I think, because (as you said) you are going to upload CSV.